# Adding JPanels through a loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, jpanel, grid-layout

**Made it work!** Thank you guys! 
The code follows. I used `BoxLayout` since I thought it'd be ideal for stacking questions one on top of the other, but now I got issues with the layout... When I stack several questions the question panels start overlapping. Any thoughts?

[image: What I wanted...]

```
            panels1 = new MultipleChoice[5];
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        panels1[i]= new MultipleChoice();
        panels1[i].setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        add(panels1[i]);


    }
    setVisible(true);
```

---

I'm working on designing an Online Test applet.
 A test has multiple choice and true/false questions. To set up a test I created two `JPanel` classes, one for the multiple choice question and one for the true/false questions. So when a test is created I'll just dynamically add these panels to a `JPanel` container according to the non-fixed number of questions.

First, how can I dynamically add new panels to a panel? I thought about declaring an array of the `JPanel` type. I created and then add objects of this panel class using a `for` loop:

```
MultitipleChoicePanel[] PanelArray;

for (...){
   PanelArray[i] =  new MultipleChoicePanel();
   containerpanel.add(PanelArray[i]);
   }
```

I don't know if this is technically possible. 
 This is my first time using Swing, and I tried doing this but obviously it didn't work.
 Does anyone have an idea how correctly dynamically add these panels?

Second, which of the layout managers is best suited for the container panel in order to fit every new panel added right under the previous one? 
 I thought about dynamically setting up a `GridLayout` of one column and add rows as I add panels. But I've been really struggling modifying swings dynamically.

 Any suggestions?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The code you posted should work if you intialize the array and only loop for the maximum number of items in your array.

Comment: You CAN dynamically add panels with a loop. Since you're new to swing, make sure to read about layouts for your container to understand exactly HOW your panels will fit in.

Comment: `FlowLayout` put them right each one, (it's jpanel default layout), also is not bad to call revalidate() and repaint() after you added all the panels

Comment: @nachokk: is right. Please accept the best answer, and up-vote all of the answers to show appreciation for their attempts to help you.

Answer (score 5):

`JPanel` default layout is `FlowLayout` and add each component by default to the right so it would fit your problem.

You also may interested in [swingx](https://swingx.java.net/) they have `HorizontalLayout`.

Example:

```
//in some place
 JPanel myBigPanel = new JPanel();
 myBigPanel.setLayout(new HorizontalLayout()); // swingx api

List<MultitipleChoicePanel> panelList = new ArrayList<>();
// panelList.add(new MultipleChoicePanel()).. .n times

for(MultipleChoicePanel mp : panelList){
 myBigPanel.add(mp);
}

myBigPanel.revalidate(); // revalidate should call repaint but who knows
myBigPanel.repaint();
```

[How to use various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

Answer (score 3):

> how correctly dynamically add these panels?

After adding components to a visible GUI you need to do:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Answer (score 1):

> "and then add objects of this panel class using a for loop:.....I dont know if its technically possible"

As far as an array of panels, I would do it with an arraylist and do it similarly to how you did it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

ArrayList<MultipleChoicePanel> array = new ArrayList<MultipleChoicePanel>();
for(...){
     array.add(new MultipleChoicePanel());
     containerPanel.add(array.get(i));
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the OP

Comment: sorry, he declared that loop and asked about it "First, how can I dynamically add new panels to a panel?", so I addressed that part and gave him a good solution. Similarly other posts only identified a portion of the question as well...

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.*;
```

import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaSwing extends JApplet  {

```
public void init(){
    Container content = getContentPane();

    JScrollPane pane= new JScrollPane();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));    

    panel.add(addPanel("title121"));
    panel.add(addPanel("title112"));
    panel.add(addPanel("title12"));
    panel.add(addPanel("title11"));
    pane.getViewport().add(panel);

    content.add(pane); 
}

public static JPanel addPanel(String title){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(new JButton(title));
    return panel;
}
```

}

Comment: THis will help for dynamic panel adding in the JApplet. Here scroll pane is used for showing your dynamic content vertically based on your requirement