# Java how to make many buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I tried to create buttons in my JFrame but they didnt appears...

```
private void btButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
       for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) { 
            JButton btn = new JButton(); 
            //System.out.print(i);
            btn.setText("Button " + i);
            System.out.print(btn.getText() + " ");
       }
}
```

Comment: Where you added them to frame ?You are just creating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hanve'nt added them to frame.

Try

```
 for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) { 
        JButton btn = new JButton(); 
        //System.out.print(i);
        btn.setText("Button " + i);
        frame.add(btn);                 //adding to frame
        System.out.print(btn.getText() + " ");
    }
```

After the loop do not forget to  call `repaint` and `revalidate` to see the changes.

Comment: but i'm using swing JFrame NetBeans style, so i'm dont creating an Frame normally, and if i put that in my funcion JFrame(), the function isnt recognizing the "btn"...

Comment: there you miss notifier revalidate, this is reason for any of down_voters here

Comment: @mKorbel Oh.I see.I thought that is quite obvious thing to do and added only essential part.Thanks for the info.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ now you fix it -1 removed

Comment: @user2770696 That should not happen.All the buttons have same string?

Comment: @SURESHATTA no, i saw the problem, i didnt put the size.. But i put the size and now is okay! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not adding the buttons to the frame. Here you have an example how to add JPanels horizontally [Adding JPanels through a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621185/adding-jpanels-through-a-loop/17621369#17621369)

```
  private void btButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) { 
            JButton btn = new JButton(); 
            btn.setText("Button " + i);
            //assuming `this` is a jframe
            this.add(btn);      
        }
           this.revalidate();
           this.repaint();
    }
```

Comment: see my comment to Reimeus

Comment: no idea, have to wait for explanations, maybe is there important reason

Comment: @mKorbel no explanations xD